# TextInputLayout Text Color in different states

Tags: android

I want to change the text color of TextInputLayout in all states.
Means when it Edittext has focus / When editext do not have focus and edittext is is not empty

I am doing like this.

```
     <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextInputLayoutHint"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/location"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                style="@style/MyEditTextAppearance"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:hint="@string/location" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


 <style name="TextInputLayoutHint" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/edittext_hint_small</item>

    </style>
```

I work find when my edittext has focus, however when edittext do not have focus it changes its hint text color to same as what edittext  hint color is.